# Create a Nuget package VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget-package, pack, dnu

I want to create a Nuget Package from an exiting VS 2015 ASP NET 5 Project. Its not an empty project, I have my own folder structure and dependencies in this project. What I need here is when any developer installs this package the package should create necessary folders and files in the target project.

I want this basically to have a standard project structure which can be used by developers which will have the boilerplate code.

I tried using Nuget Package Explorer, but when I install it on a web application it does not create any folders that I have in the package. Here is a snapshot of the Nuget Package explorer

[image: My package]

I also tried `dnu pack` command, but not sure what else I need to have in project.json to make all the folders and files part of the package.

Is Nuget package the correct way to go, or should it be a VS 2015 Project template?

Really appreciate if anyone could give me some pointers on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget transforms don't look to be supported in ASP.NET 5 as yet.  Here's the intended future [spec](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Content-v2-for-project.json).

For now, creating a Project Template, [instructions here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx), looks the way to go.

Comment: Those were nice links. I tried the template approach but somehow it does not create the folders and files that were exported form my project. Now this does not make sense cause each and every article I followed to create a Project does the same steps. May be I am doing some stupid mistake.